# On the proof of the complete regularity of topological vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis

From "Functional analysis" by Walter Rudin, page 41, the exercise 21: 
Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $0$ in a topological vector space in $X$. Prove that there is a real continuous function $f$ on $X$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ outside V.

Can we use the term "normed vector space" instead of "topological vector space", and solve that exercise with tools of pure elementary functional analysis, just normed vector space, no topology structure here? If yes, how can we do that? (Furthermore, if necessary, use the term "open ball centered at the origin" instead of "neighborhood of $0$")

Just wondering, since I have to deal mainly with normed vector space now, not topological vector space yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the case of a normed vector space, you can explicitly construct one such function. In particular, as you have said, you can replace neighborhoods with balls (which one cannot normally do on an arbitrary topological vector space). Can you construct this function in the case of a finite-dimensional vector space? The arbitrary-dimensional case is similar.

Comment: Let us denote the open ball $B(0,r)$. I tried this function:
$f(x)=|x|/r$ if $x\in B(0,r)$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x \in X \setminus B(0,r)$.

Comment: Consider the function constructed above, we have $f(0)=|0| / r = 0$, $f(x) = 1$ outside the ball, and this function is continuous.
Is that the function you mentioned above?

PS: |.| is the norm.

Comment: Yup, that looks good.

Comment: I think that function works well in both finite-dimensional and arbitrary-dimensional vector space.